How to reassign multiple let variable in angular 18
How to reassign multiple let values in angular18
    let one,two,three; 
    let fun=()=> {
      return ({one: "tt", two:"uu", three: "vv"})
    }
   

Demo:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pzes9v?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

This is a typescript thing, not linked to angular.
const values = {one: "tt", two:"uu", three: "vv"};
let one;
let two;
let three;
console.log(values);
({one, two, three} = values);
console.log(one);
console.log(two);
console.log(three);

You need to add parenthesis around your destructuring assignment.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment
Also note that your values is never set, which won't work
in your example:
 ngOnInit(): void {
     let one;
     let two;
     let three; 
     let values = {one: "tt", two:"uu", three: "vv"};
   
     ({one,two,three} = values);
 
     console.log(one);
     console.log(two);
     console.log(three);
 }

or with a function
  ngOnInit(): void {
     let one, two, three;
     let fun = () => {
       return { one: 'tt', two: 'uu', three: 'vv' };
     };

     ({ one, two, three } = fun());

     console.log(one);
     console.log(two);
     console.log(three);
  }


This is not working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5p5x3r?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

You know the answer?

it is working, please write logical code

Getting error: Error in src/app/app.component.ts (20:5)
The left-hand side of an assignment expression must be a variable or a property access.

Check my code. I am using function for return

check your code, you're trying to destructure a function and also not placing correctly the parenthesis as stated in my answer

Can you edit in the stackblitz?

check my answer

You are great.Thank ou
